# periodic error dialog (default Email app related) on Windows 10, appears to be CortanaMapiHelper, should I be concerned?

Tags: windows-10, process, virus, process-explorer, cortana

I'm running Windows 10 64-bit.  Periodically (maybe daily?), I get the below dialog appearing on my machine.

[image: error dialog]

I normally just click OK and move on.  This time, I ran Process Explorer, then used the "Find Windows Process" icon on the dialog to see which process was involved.  This took me to a dllhost.exe process.  The command line for that process included, "/Processid:{3BFADDE5-09ED-42AE-8190-2E68B650CFE6}"  I looked this up in the registry and I see that this is identified as CortanaMapiHelper.

1) A search online of the error message suggested doing what it says, i.e. setting the default mail association to something.  I almost did this, but when this happens I am not doing anything that would be intending to send an Email.  I use Thunderbird as my Email client and I am not doing anything in Thunderbird when this happens.  In thinking more about it, even if this approach would remove the message, does that mean something is sending Email on my behalf?

2) Another result from searching online was an indication that dllhost.exe -could- be something malicious, but they seemed to be associated with instances that did not have a clear /Processid argument.  In this case it does and clearly indicates Cortana.

3) Although I have Cortana and have used it for reminders, I really don't use it for anything else.  Certainly not sending Email.

Any ideas/suggestions/etc?  The dialog showing periodically is annoying, but I'm wondering if this is a sign of something worse.

Comment: I could not find this post by the dialog message but the GUID 

Answer (score 3):

I found [this post](http://nerdshack.info/windows-10-and-the-outlook-popup-of-anger/) to be useful. In short: rename the registry key for the process ID so that the DLL launch fails. You have to become the owner of the key and give yourself full control for the rename to succeed.

Comment: interesting; makes sense that this would get rid of the dialog.  I'm curious though what exactly its trying to do and why its getting triggered.

Comment: For me it got triggered by enabling Cortana searches. There is a round icon in the task bar on the bottom left of the screen. Clicking that for the first time seemed to enable that.

Comment: yes. it definitely seems to be Cortana.  I get this when I'm not doing anything related to Cortana though.  Which is why it seemed strange to me that it would be, in the background accessing Email features.

Comment: I would guess, Cortana takes an inventory of available interfaces at startup. The failure is somehow not caught and shown to the user.(If Microsoft wants to do something sneaky, the surely have better ways than sending mails.)